# Matching russian vowels in C++

Tags: c++, cyrillic

I wanted to write a function which returns true if a given character is a russian vowel. But the results I get are strange to me. This is what I've got so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool is_vowel_p(char working_char)
// returns true if the character is a russian vowel
{
    string matcher = "аяё×эеуюыи";

    if (find(matcher.begin(), matcher.end(), working_char) != matcher.end())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


void main()
{
    cout << is_vowel_p('е') << endl; // russian vowel
    cout << is_vowel_p('Ж') << endl; // russian consonant

    cout << is_vowel_p('D') << endl; // latin letter
}
```

The result is:

```
1
1
0
```

what is strange to me. I expected the following result:

```
1
0
0
```

It's seems that there is some kind of internal mechanism which I don't know yet. I'm at first interested in how to fix this function to work properly. And second, what is going on there, that I get this result.

Comment: It may be just me but I don't think that `Ж` is contained in `аяё×эеуюыи`

Comment: @Renan: Which is why "0" is the second expected result.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you can shorten the function down a little: `return find(matcher.begin(), matcher.end(), working_char) != matcher.end();` You can also mark the `matcher` string as `const` since it never changes, and maybe even `static`.

Comment: The code works fine: http://ideone.com/CBJoD4 (although your string matcher is incorrect. It should be "аяёоэеуюыи")

Comment: @icepack: It doesn't work fine; I suspect that compiler converts the out-of-range characters into values which happen to give the expected results, while the OP's doesn't.

Comment: C++11 has some support for Unicode, you may want to look into that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`string` and `char` are only guaranteed to represent characters in the basic character set - which does not include the Cyrillic alphabet.

Using `wstring` and `wchar_t`, and adding `L` before the string and character literals to indicate that they use wide characters, should allow you to work with those letters.

Also, for portability you need to include `<algorithm>` for `find`, and give `main` a return type of `int`.

Comment: It does if the system default locale is Cyrillic (CP1251). In Russia, it's a pretty safe assumption. But brittle otherwise.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: Indeed (assuming that the string literal uses a fixed 8-bit encoding, not UTF-8 for example); as I said, it's only *guaranteed* to support the basic set (Latin letters, digits, and a few puncuation characters).

Comment: Interesting situation, actually. In this example it doesn't really matter whether layout is cyrillic or not. Since the input is `char`, anything above 7-bits will be cast to it.

Comment: @icepack: No, `char` must be at least 8 bits, and won't be truncated. So if you know that the string uses a fixed-size 8-bit representation including the characters you're interested in, then it should work. Probably. I'd stick with Unicode, myself.

Comment: Sorry, changed my original comment. I meant that any value > 128 will cause signed integer overflow (and probably wrap around but it's really UB)

Comment: @icepack: Yes, on further thought you do get unspecified values if `char` is signed. One more reason not to mess around with non-ASCII 8-bit encodings.

Comment: I've tried similar code, specifically with Russian and CP1251, many times - it *works* on all conceivable C compilers, as long as you're careful with codepages. Signed/unsigned char issues do come up occasionally, but not in OP's example.

Comment: Agree with Seva. As long as the compiler and runtime codepages are consistent, this should work. I.e. if it does't work, the main suspect is the codepage used by the compiler.

Comment: @MSalters: So how would one ensure consistency? I'm afraid I've no idea how these weird encodings work; I stick to ASCII and Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

C++ source code is ASCII. You are entering unicode characters. The comparison is being done using 8 bit values. I bet one of the vowels fulfills the following:-

```
vowel & 255 == (code point for 'Ж') & 255
```

You need to use unicode functions to do this, not ASCII functions, i.e. use functions that require wchar_t values. Also, make sure your compiler can parse the non-ASCII vowel string. Using MS VC, the compiler requires:-

```
L"аяё×эеуюыи" or TEXT("аяё×эеуюыи")
```

the latter is a macro that adds the `L` when compiling with unicode support.

Convert the code to use wchar_t and it should work.

Comment: @icepack There is no "Russian ASCII". ASCII is 7-bit encoding. You probably mean Russian codepage.

Comment: Russian alphabet is present with Russian ASCII layout. This is the correct direction but Ж is present in the 8-bit ASCII table. See @MikeSeymour answer and comments

Comment: @milleniumbug Full ASCII table is 8-bit. The second part is less useful but it definitely exists.

Comment: @icepack No. ASCII is 7-bit encoding. Second part is defined by codepages. CP1251 is a Russian codepage.

Comment: @milleniumbug Second part of 8-bit ASCII table is defined by codepage. That doesn't make it not belonging to the ASCII

Comment: @icepack If it's 8-bit, it's not ASCII, it's ASCII + one bit. The extra characters don't __belong__ to ASCII. "ASCII includes definitions for 128 characters" (Wikipedia quote). Codepages are superset of ASCII, but they are __not__ ASCII.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30077/discussion-between-milleniumbug-and-icepack)

Answer (score 2):

Very useful function in locale.h

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
```

Past this in the beginning of the program.
Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    printf("Здравствуй, мир!\n");//Hello, world!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your system default locale is Russian, and make sure your file is saved as codepage 1251 (Cyrillic/Windows). If it's saved as Unicode, this won't ever work.

The system default locale is the one used by non-Unicode-compliant programs. It's in Control Panel, under Regional settings.

Alternatively, rewritte to use `wstring` and `wchar_t` and `L""` string/char literals.

Comment: It's quite likely that your compiler will be Unicode-compliant. That's entirely unrelated to the fact that it needs _a_ locale when parsing you non-Unicode source file.